# Improving boot/grub questions and answers

Tags: discussion, best-practice

If you look at the [grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/grub), [grub2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/grub2), and [boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/boot) tags you'll likely find pretty vague and incomplete questions and answers. I personally consider these 3 tags as the ones that we could improve the most on this site.

This is probably because:

- It's insanely difficult to troubleshoot boot problems remotely.
- New users likely have no idea how to troubleshoot boot problems.
- The documentation is [lengthy and complicated](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2), because booting operating systems is complicated.
- It's difficult to have general guidelines when people have all sorts of combinations of hardware and needs.

I've been wondering how to help do this better. We could of course offtopic them and send them to file bugs but remember that the person's computer is utterly broken so we should at least be making an effort to help get them back on their feet instead of sending them away. However it can be difficult to get that information out of someone who can't boot.

Ideas on how to improve this?

Answer (score 3):

Ofcourse it is little bit difficult for us to help at the first sight.Because we need more details like their hard drive information,file system type etc etc.So the user when asking for help,should post the output of bootscript results.Bootscript answers many of our questions,also it says whether it is wubi installation or dual boot installation.So now it is quite easy for us to troubleshoot their problems.

Comment: Ok, then perhaps we should ask a question like "Where can I find boot information" so we have a nice well done answer to link people instead of sending them to the website, sort of like how I did for the hardware logs: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Comment: Yep you are right..

Comment: hey, it is X. Y. Z. not X.Y.Z.